# Class Composition Constructor d Must Explicitly initialize the reference member

Tags: c++, constructor

I am really stuck with the problem here.
So basically I have a `Stock` class and a `BuyOrder` class.The `BuyOrder` class takes the `Stock` class as a member so it knows which stock to buy. When the stock is created, it takes in a company name and initializes with random prices. Then I can create a buy order takes in  `bidPrice`,`bidQuantity`,`Stock` arguments.

In the `main` I want to create an array of `BuyOrder` to store the orders. Then every time the user created an order, the order can be stored.

My first approach is to declare `BuyOrder buyList[100]`. This way every time the user created an order, I can use the set functions to set each `buyList[i]` and then increment i. However, when I declare `BuyOrder buyList[100]`in `main`. It says `No matching constructor for initialization of 'BuyStock buyList[100]'` I went back to `BuyOrder.cpp` try to add a default constructor `BuyOrder::BuyOrder(){}` then it shows the error:`Constructor for 'BuyOder'must explicitly initialize the reference member 'buyStock'`.

I don't know how to proceed from here. Very much appreciated.

Below is part of BuyOrder.cpp since it way too long and the rest part are just function definitions.

```
BuyOrder::BuyOrder{double price, int quantity, Stock &s)
:buyPrice{price},
 buyQuantity{quantity},
 buyStock{s}{}

void BuyOrder::setBuyStock(Stock stock){
    buyStock = stock;
}

void BuyOrder::setBuyOrderPrice(double price) {
    buyPrice = price;
}

void BuyOrder::setBuyOrderQuantity(int quantity) {
    buyQuantity = quantity;
```

Below is BuyOrder.h

```
#ifndef BUYORDER_H
#define BUYORDER_H
#include <ctime>
#include<iostream>
#include "Stock.h"


class BuyOrder {
    friend void getCurrentTime();

public:
    BuyOrder(double , int , Stock & );

    void setBuyStock(Stock);
    void setBuyOrderPrice(double price);
    void setBuyOrderQuantity(int quantity);

    double getBuyOrderPrice();
    int getBuyOrderQuantity();

    void placeBuyOrder();
    void checkExcute();

    void modifyBuyOrder();
    void cancelBuyOrder();

    double getHighestBidPrice();
    int getHighestBidPriceQuantity();

    double getLowestBidPrice();
    int getLowestBidPriceQuantity();

private:
    double buyPrice;
    int buyQuantity;
    bool excute = false;
    Stock &buyStock;
    time_t t;

};
#endif
```

This is the Stock.h

```
#ifndef STOCK_H
#define STOCK_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Stock {

    friend void getCurrentTime();


public:
    Stock();
    Stock(string nameOfCompany);

    int getBidTerms();
    int getAskTerms();
    void printStockInfo();
    void initialize();
    void sortBid();
    void sortAsk();

    string nameOfCompany;
    string currentTime;

    vector<double> askPrice;
    vector<int> askQuantity;

    vector<double> bidPrice;
    vector<int> bidQuantity;

    int bidTerm;
    int askTerm;

};
#endif
```

and this is Stock.cpp excluding the long function definitions

```
#include "Stock.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
using namespace std;


void getCurrentTime() {

    time_t rawTime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time(&rawTime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawTime);
    cout << asctime(timeinfo);
}

Stock::Stock(){}

Stock::Stock(string companyName) :nameOfCompany{ companyName } {
    initialize();
    sortBid();
    sortAsk();
}
```

Comment: References (`T&` variables) and constants (`const T` variables) must be explicitly initialised by the class' constructor; if the class has a default constructor, it therefore must initialise them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `BuyOrder` class (which you don't show us, and should) contains a reference member (`Stock &buyStock;`), you have to set that reference to something within any constructor for the class.  This means that you can't normally use a default constructor, as that does not initialize the reference.

Possible solutions include changing `buyStock` to not be a reference, changing it to be a pointer (which can be nulled out for those cases where it doesn't represent an order yet), or changing containers from a fixed size array to something that can be resized, like a `vector`.

Comment: So I changed the containers, using 'vector' but when I trying to declare BuyStock list[10], it shows me the same error. I have updated the codes above